# Should I be using iptables or ufw?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, ufw

I know of iptables. I know of ufw. I've been using ufw in the past just because it's easier to setup and use.

However, which one *should* I be using? Is iptables more secure? Is ufw more stable?

I have no idea, hence why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ufw ( uncomplicated firewall) is an easy to use front end for iptables. Stick with ufw for the configuration as you're already using iptables.

Comment: Note that iptables comes preinstalled in any Linux distribution so it is good to know how it works. It also has the advantage to be able to create temporary firewall rules by default that will be reset after computer restart. I used ufw and switched to iptables because ufw was uninstalled automatically after an Ubuntu upgrade where I had to remove broken python dependencies, which also removed ufw and made me lost all the firewall rules even after reinstalling ufw...